# Upgrade to Linux kernel 4.15.0-44 in Ubuntu 18.04 breaks VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

A recent upgrade to the Linux 4.15.0-44 kernel broke VirtualBox on my system. I'm running Ubuntu 18.0.4. Haven't had time to investigate, but rebooting to 4.15.0-43 allowed virtual system to be booted.

Just wondering if anybody else has had this issue?

Comment: I didn't try with VirtualBox, but the upgrade broke my multi-monitor setup (I have two external monitors, connecting them just froze the whole system). Something seems to be wrong with that version...

Comment: What Virtualbox version are you using and how did you install it? I am using 5.2.26 on two systems and I have installed it from the official Oracle repo. Both copies work as they should after this kernel update on both the host and the guest systems. In general, it's better to use the Virtualbox versions offered by Oracle rather than the one in the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 2):

Canonical seems to have recognized this issue and released another version already. They probably just reverted it back to 4.15.0-43 but called it 4.15.0-45 just to make a quick fix, so we'll probably see another kernel version soon after they resolve 4.15.0-44's issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your problem, but this update pretty much broke everything for me as I'm not able to boot / or booting into black screen (not sure if nvidia driver was at fault but it did not get updated - only the kernel).
This is due to an issue with the kernel not being able to detect USB devices (I have an external USB drive attached), but even after disabling the disk it still won't boot.
After reverting to the previous kernel the problem(s) disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop there were several negative effects, it was not trackable to dedicated actions. Examples:

- spurious USB oops messages
- login in gnome UI session leads to a black screen (no way out, no mouse, no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd>)
- shutdown does not drive the machine into the right power state (energy remains on)
  ...

This 4.15.0-44 was a pure nightmare...